# Error Application-defined or object-defined error in excel macro from macro Recording

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a trouble with my recorded formula using Macro Recording. Here is the script:

```
Range("M2").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(MID(RC[-3],SEARCH(""/BRI/AC"",RC[-3],1)+8,7),IFERROR(MID(RC[-3],SEARCH(""TG00006"",RC[-3],1),7),IFERROR(MID(RC[-3],SEARCH(""CA002"",RC[-3],1),5),IFERROR(MID(RC[-3],SEARCH(""/TUNAI"",RC[-3],1)-5,5),IFERROR(MID(RC[-3],SEARCH(""/BRI"",RC[-3],1)+17,7),IFERROR(MID(RC[-3],SEARCH(""/MS?"",RC[-3],1)+1,6),IFERROR(MID(RC[-3],SEARCH(""/MM?"",RC[-3],1)+1,7),IFERROR(MID" & "SEARCH(""/BM"",RC[-3],1)+1,5),IFERROR(MID(RC[-3],FIND(""/KS"",RC[-3],1)+1,5),IFERROR(MID(RC[-3],SEARCH(""/BR"",RC[-3],1)+1,5),IFERROR(MID(RC[-3],SEARCH(""/BG"",RC[-3],1)+1,5),IFERROR(MID(RC[-3],SEARCH(""/T?"",RC[-3],1)+1,7),""""))))))))))))"
```

The error highlight is from the ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1. Can anyone here can help me about this error? Because this formula is running well if I manually input it on the cell. I just try to make automation Formatting using Macro in excel.

Comment: Can you please post your actual formula in cell M2?

Comment: This is my actual formula =IFERROR(MID(J2;SEARCH("/BRI/AC";J2;1)+8;7);IFERROR(MID(J2;SEARCH("TG00006";J2;1);7);IFERROR(MID(J2;SEARCH("CA002";J2;1);5);IFERROR(MID(J2;SEARCH("/TUNAI";J2;1)-5;5);IFERROR(MID(J2;SEARCH("/BRI";J2;1)+17;7);IFERROR(MID(J2;SEARCH("/MS?";J2;1)+1;6);IFERROR(MID(J2;SEARCH("/MM?";J2;1)+1;7);IFERROR(MID(J2;SEARCH("/BM";J2;1)+1;5);IFERROR(MID(J2;FIND("/KS";J2;1)+1;5);IFERROR(MID(J2;SEARCH("/BR";J2;1)+1;5);IFERROR(MID(J2;SEARCH("/BG";J2;1)+1;5);IFERROR(MID(J2;SEARCH("/T?";J2;1)+1;7);""))))))))))))

Comment: I use this formula to extract the customer code from description field in column J

Comment: Replace `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ` in your code with `Debug.Print` (followed by your formula). This will output the formula string you are actually writing to the cell in the Immediate pane. You will see that the quotation marks aren't as you expect. You need to escape them, meaning, place quotation marks within quotation marks in  the formula string. `Debug.Print """"` will print a single quotation mark to the Immediate pane

Comment: @Variatus I already try your suggestion using Debug.Print to see the actual formula showed in the immediate pane. But I think nothing is wrong with my formula, I already check with my original formula in other worksheet. Because I made those formula using Macro Recorder (I place the cell in M2 press F2 and then enter then stop recording) and then using those formed ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 in other worksheet (my Automated Xlsm file) as a part of Formatting sequence

Comment: If there is nothing wrong with the formula (which I have now confirmed through trial) there must be something wrong with the idea. Further testing can only confirm this and perhaps find the reason (probably the IFERROR statements). I fully understand that you want someone else (VBA) to enter this monster formula. What I don't understand is why you want a worksheet function while VBA is at your disposal. Look at getting VBA to find the result. Worst case, use a UDF.

Comment: @Variatus No, I think you miss understood, I don't want someone else to enter my formula. As I explained it before, I already have this formula and worksheet working well but I try to make the formatting process automatic using Macro so the end user doesn't need to do the Formatting sequence manually. But I'm very beginner in macro and VBA Excel, that's why when the Macro I created the running is error I try to looking the answer here.

Comment: @Variatus By the way that's not a monster formula (I take that as a complement :-)  ), as I told you earlier I make those formula to extract the customer code from description field. So every single IFERROR and SEARCH statement represent variant of the description field I try to extract.

Comment: Yes. It's definitely a compliment! But it's also definitely a monster. In VBA, every IFERROR comes in a separate line of code, to the effect that it's much easier to see what the code is doing. Therefore it's easier to write and easier to maintain or modify. Please try to shift your argument from "why can't VBA write my formula" to "why can't VBA to get the result".  If there is no convincing argument why it ***must*** be a formula VBA is the obvious solution. No kudos for that but no monster, either.